# Dockerfile from Docker Hub repository

Tags: python-2.7, docker, dockerfile, centos7

I'm trying to create Dockerfile for Centos 7 and python 2.7
I found one at the Docker Hub:
https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/python-27-centos7
But I don't see any tutorial How to create Dockerfile using this image - I see pull command only

Actually I want to add some dependencies and python packages

So my question in general - if I found some suitable image on DockerHub - How to use it in my Dockerfile?

I just tried:

```
FROM python-27-centos7
```

But got next error:

> failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB:
> failed to load cache key: pull access denied, repository does not
> exist or may require authorization: server message:
> insufficient_scope: authorization failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help if you did this:

```
FROM centos/python-27-centos7
```

> So my question in general - if I found some suitable image on DockerHub - How to use it in my Dockerfile?

It would be best if you used the full image name:

```
User/Repo:Tag
```

The default value for the tag is "latest"

```
FROM centos/python-27-centos7:latest
```